# How can i pass ENV variables between make targets

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have like this in makefile

```
target1:
       export var1=test
       $(MAKE) target2

target2:
       echo $(var1)
```

This is coming as empty

I have other depencies so i want to set variable in first target and then all children dependencies should be able to access that

EDIT:

```
.ONESHELL:

target1:
        export var1=test
        echo $(var1)
```

output

```
make target1
export var1=test
echo
```

Comment: What you have is correct according to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html. Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable Makefile that demonstrates the issue you're seeing.

Comment: `$(var1)` is a make variable, not an environment variable.  Are you trying to make `echo $${var1}` work?

Comment: @WilliamPursell sorry that was my mistake , its not working , i tried everything its coming as `echo blank`. if i do echo $${var1} then it is aslo empty

Comment: @WilliamPursell Make automatically imports environment variables.

Comment: @user657267, yes, but assigning a variable in make doesn't cause that variable to be in the environment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default make invokes a new shell environment for each recipe, the `export`ed variable on the first line isn't in scope for the second.

You can fix this in multiple ways:

Export the variable with make's `export` directive

```
target1: export var1 := test
target1:
    $(MAKE) target2
```

---

Use make's command line variable assignment

```
target1:
    $(MAKE) target2 var1=test
```

---

Use shell command variable assignment

```
target1:
    var1=test $(MAKE) target2
```

---

Combine the two commands in a single recipe

```
target1:
    export var1=test; $(MAKE) target2
```

---

Force make to pass all recipes to the same shell instance

```
.ONESHELL:

target1:
    export var1=test
    $(make) target2
```

Comment: I tried ur example and in second line i type `echo $(var1)` it comes as blank

Comment: @Karl What version of make are you using? `ONESHELL` was added in 3.82. If you are using an older version you'll need to upgrade or use one of the other methods.

Comment: Mine is 3.81 . I even tried  `export var1=test; echo $(var1)` it still come as empty

Comment: @Karl Well you've changed your example, that won't work because `$(var1)` is expanded before the line is passed to the shell. `export var1=test; echo $$var1` will work.

Comment: THanks for that,  Is there any way to oneshell in previous versions

Comment: @Karl Not that I know of.

Comment: you just need to pass it on using $(MAKE) X=1

Comment: Just remember to use $(MAKE) that is all