# LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't contain exported path

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

Tried to export the path of the .so through the make file in the below mentioned way

install-data-am:

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'$(PWD)'
    echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but if do echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH it is still blank. Please help me on this, thanks in advance

Comment: What's with the double `$` signs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i pass ENV variables between make targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927419/how-can-i-pass-env-variables-between-make-targets)

Comment: But still it is blank. Followed the same way as suggested in  "How can i pass ENV variables between make targets"

Answer (score 3):

Each target statement in the `Makefile` is an independent statement that gets executed in a subshell. After it gets executed, `make` starts a new subshell to execute the next statement.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'$(PWD)'
```

`make` starts a child process that executes this command. This command finishes executing, and `make` resumes with the next command.

```
echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

`make` starts a child process to execute this command. The previous command finished executing already. The previous command did set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in its environment, but that's ancient history. That child process, and its environment, went to that great bit bucket in the sky. This new process knows nothing about it.

You need to execute everything as one statement, one shell mini-script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'$(PWD)'; echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When writing very long shell mini-scripts, to be executed as a single child process by `make`, long lines can be split with backslashes:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'$(PWD)'; \
    echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thank you very much