# How to pass environment variable to docker container using `make` command?

Tags: bash, docker, makefile, environment-variables

I have a docker container running and I want to execute command `make target-branch branch="branch_name"` so that inside container I have `TARGET` environment variable set to `"branch_name"`.

I tried writing the following in `Makefile`

```
target-branch:
    @ export TARGET=$(branch)
```

It didn't work, after going inside container and executing `printenv` there is no such environment variable.

Also tried exporting it using bash script

```
--- Makefile ---
target-branch:
    @ sh scripts/set_target_branch.sh $(branch)

--- scripts/set_target_branch.sh ---
#!/bin/bash

export TARGET="$1"
echo $TARGET
```

After `make target-branch branch="branch_name"`, `echo` inside script outputs `"branch_name"`, but the `TARGET` variable still absents inside the container upon `printenv`.

Just in case, my [Dockerfile](https://snippi.com/s/78qyjm5), [docker-compose.yml](https://snippi.com/s/i38i7yx),

Comment: what does `echo $(branch)` do inside your target? Another option is to set the env var on the same line as your command: `TARGET=$(BRANCH) docker run ...`

Comment: `echo` is just to show that `TARGET` variable has the proper value upon script execution. I want to set it while container is running already, so I can change it any amount of times while container is up.

Comment: are dynamic env vars possible with Docker? I thought a restart was always required. This answer uses files and volumes for dynamic values coming from the host: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894934 - may be useful here

Comment: You are apparently trying to export a shell variable from a child process to its parent process. This is not possible. It is the parent process that must set the environment variable. One ugly workaround would be to use your Makefile to print the export command (`@printf 'export TARGET="%s"\n' "$(branch)"`) and use `eval` when invoking `make`: `eval "$(make target-branch branch="branch_name")"` (warning: this is dangerous and your Makefile shall print only this, nothing else). But directly typing `export TARGET="branch_name"` is much simpler and natural.

Comment: And if you are trying to run `make` from outside your container things are even worse: you cannot directly set the environment variables of a process inside your container from outside. And this is a good thing (imagine the safety and security issues if this was possible...)

Comment: If this is what you want (set the variable from outside) one possibility would be to mount a volume in your container, regularly update a file in the volume from the outside of your container, and use its content inside your container. The file could be a source-able shell script (`export TARGET="branch_name"`) or anything you want. Of course this solution also has safety and security implications that you should consider.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that each `make` recipe runs a subprocess whose environment disappears as soon as it exits. To successfully `export` something, you need to run whatever needs to read what you `export`ed as a subprocess of the process which did the `export`. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: As an aside, littering your `Makefile` with `@` makes debugging harder. If you don't want to see what it's doing, use `make -s`

Comment: Does [How can i pass ENV variables between make targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927419/how-can-i-pass-env-variables-between-make-targets) describe this case?  I can't totally tell from this question how the `TARGET` variable is intended to be used.

Comment: @DavidMaze , it's less about targets, and more about just passing/changing environment variable inside container

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larry , @RenaudPacalet and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose)

It seems that the better way to handle environment variable in this case is to just set it upon `docker start` (`docker compose-up` in my case), so what I did:

```
--- .env ---
TARGET_BRANCH=master

--- docker-compose.yml ---
services:
  my-app:
    environment: 
      TARGET: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"

--- Makefile ---
start:
    IMAGE=$(IMAGE) \
    CONTAINER=$(CONTAINER) \
    docker-compose up -d
```

So to change `TARGET` you would just change `TARGET_BRANCH` in `.env` to whatever is needed, and then execute `make start` to update it inside container.